# Site down for some users and I can't find the issue

Tags: apache, server, downtime

Hoping to get some advice, I'm getting feedback from users in seveal regions around the world (Asia, Africa) that a site I run is down for them.

When I check myself it's fine, checking the server all the services are fine. I can't find any issue - what can I do to figure this out?

Comment: Things I would check:  DNS Health checks like [this](http://intodns.com/) one; Traceroutes from different locations like [this](http://visualroute.visualware.com/) one; Web filter checks like [this](http://csi.websense.com/) one; Website load tests from different countries like [this](http://www.webpagetest.org/) one.

Comment: Everything looks good! The only issue is with my SOA refresh value is the same as my SOA expire value which the DNS diag tool didn't like... but that hasn't changed recently and the sites been working well for weeks.

Comment: That's likely not the issue. I'd suggest asking those you're getting emails from to do traceroutes to your site from their location/ISP. If they get blocked at the first hop, then there's a filter on their firewall, or possibly with their ISP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check that your site is available from outside of your network. You can use sites like http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ to check that your site is accessible. If it passes this test, then likely there is nothing for you to do.

I have seen issues such as this where a network is failing to resolve the domain name, or fails to deliver either the request or response packets. This can happen especially when there are routing problems but also when packet loss occurs.

The user can do a nslookup to resolve the domain name. As well, they can do a ping and check for packet loss. Ultimately, a tracert or traceroute can be used to see a *proposed* route. Trace routes are not always the route that a request is made so the results may not always be conclusive.

It may be that the user needs to contact the network provider or simply wait. I often remind people that TCP/IP is not a guaranteed delivery mechanism. It has built into it the option to fail. It is the client that must retry the connection and not the network. Browsers do not retry anything. They just fail. It is the user who must retry the connection. If there is consistent failure then there is a problem. Keep in mind that requests from a browser can fail for small reasons from time to time.

Also note if your users are from a particular geographical location, or network. This may help you to know what is going on.

Otherwise just give it some time and see if there is a change.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback.
So I checked both http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ as well as http://wheresitup.com/ and go greenlights from both. However I have emails from 8 users across 8 countries all exclaiming "the site is down"! and attaching screenshots of web browsers. Many claim to have tried multiple times. All the while it's fine for me.

I'm going to try the nslookup with some of them, thanks for the advice

Comment: One more thing, should I do a graceful restart of my apache server just... for good measure? I don't often do that.

Comment: It certainly would not hurt if you have always had good luck with your server restarting okay. It would eliminate any issues on your end. Also consider if you have a firewall, router, modem, etc. These can act funny from time to time especially since so many are linux based. I have had issues with connectivity that was flakey that had nothing to do with my equipment, but a reboot of the firewall, router, and modem cleared up routing and line error issues on the telco side. Consider that as an option too.

Comment: Also consider having your users do a trace route to your domain name. There may be a common point there the trace route will fail. I have seen issues like this where it is a backbone (or other similar) provider that has routing issues. It could be your own telco or up-stream telco that is failing to route requests properly.